# MasterDetailPage shows a blank page

Tags: xaml, xamarin

My PCL starts in MyProject.Views.MainPage, and this is its source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MainPage">
    <Label Text="Hello"/>
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Content BackgroundColor="Gray" Title="MasterPage">
            <StackLayout Margin="5, 30, 5, 5">
                <Label Text="Master page"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage Padding="10">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Margin="5, 30, 5, 5">
                <Label Text="Detail page"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

I have no warnings and no errors, but when I execute the application, I only see a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two errors:

1. You need to close the `MasterDetailPage` tag at the end of the code
2. `BackgroundColor="Gray" Title="MasterPage"` these properties are availables in the `ContentPage` and you are using them inside other property (`ContentPage.Content`)

So if you make these changes you will get something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage
    x:Class="Test.Pages.MasterDetailPage1"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Label Text="Hello" />
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Master" BackgroundColor="Gray">
            <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                <Label Text="Master page" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage Padding="10">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                    <Label Text="Detail page" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

[image: Result]

I hope this can help you.